# React-native-navigation animate popping a screen?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

So I have a react-native app which is using react-native-navigation.
Whenever I click a `card` in my app, it pushes me the card screen.

What I want to achieve is the following: when swiping down from that screen, as you swipe down the screen gets smaller and the other one is in the background, but I haven't found anything that can help me with that, any packages? Also, I'd have to pop the current screen to have the other one the background, but if I pop it, the current screen can't stay and get smaller as i swipe down.
So basically I need to animate a component pop.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured it out yet, you could show the `card screen` as an overlay or modal and add a swipe-down gesture to the `Container` component of the screen and when it reaches the bottom, you could `dismissOverlay` or `dismissModal` with no animation.